# Why is there so much overhead between PHP/MySQL compared to Desktop Client/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have wordpress blog on a well-known webhosting service and each write/update through Wordpress Web is very slow and sometimes fails completely.

Whereas with a remote access to the SAME MySQL database using a desktop client it's fast and reliable ?

Comment: If mysql access on your web host is consistently slow and unreliable bring it up with their support personnel. There could be a configuration issue, ie databases on separate clusters than the web servers and some routing path messes up. Whereas when you access it with a desktop client you go via a different route.

Comment: I will ask them and will come back to this another day.

Answer (score 0):

If connecting to the db is slow the client will benefit from connection pooling.

Comment: You can messure this in your PHP code and report it as a problem if you see that getting the connection is taking a long time.